# Stray comma after 'corporate author' in the “author” field of a bibliographic entry with many authors

Tags: bibtex

I need to list a research group after other authors in the author field of a bibliographic entry. I am using the following syntax:

```
@booklet{Carter2007,
author = {Carter, RE and Lackland, DT and Cleary, PA and Yim, E and Lopes-Virella, MF and Gilbert, GE and Orchard, TJ and {The DCCT/EDIC Research Group}},
title = {{Intensive treatment of diabetes is associated with a reduced rate of peripheral arterial calcification in Diabetes Control and Complications Trial/Epidemiology of Diabetes Interventions and COmplications (DCCT/EDIC)}},
howpublished= {Paper presented at the American Diabetes Association 67\textsuperscript{th} Annual Scientific Sessions June nn\textsuperscript{nd}--26\textsuperscript{th}, Chicago, IL},
year = {2007}
}
```

This results in:

> Carter, RE, Lackland, DT, Cleary, PA, Yim, E, Lopes-Virella, MF,
>   Gilbert, GE, Orchard, TJ, and The DCCT/EDIC Research Group, .
>   Intensive treatment of diabetes is associated with a reduced rate of
>   peripheral arterial calcification in Diabetes Control and
>   Complications Trial/Epidemiology of Diabetes Interventions and
>   COmplications (DCCT/EDIC). Paper presented at the American Diabetes
>   Association 67th Annual Scientific Sessions June 22nd–26th; Chicago,
>   IL, 2007.

This is almost what I need; however, there is the comma and space after the "Group". 
I have tried enclosing the "The DCCT/EDIC Research Group" and a variety of permutations with quotes and parenthees and cannot seem to fix this. I have changed the "booklet" to "misc" to no avail.

I have also Googled "'corporate authorship' bibtex" and could not find any help.

The results I am looking for is:

> Carter, RE, Lackland, DT, Cleary, PA, Yim, E, Lopes-Virella, MF,
>   Gilbert, GE, Orchard, TJ, and The DCCT/EDIC Research Group. Intensive
>   treatment of diabetes is associated with a reduced rate of peripheral
>   arterial calcification in Diabetes Control and Complications
>   Trial/Epidemiology of Diabetes Interventions and COmplications
>   (DCCT/EDIC). Paper presented at the American Diabetes Association 67th
>   Annual Scientific Sessions June 22nd–26th; Chicago, IL, 2007.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete document which uses your `bib` entry and produces the output posted when compiled. That way, we can reproduce your problem and work on it. The output depends not only on the `bib` entry but on your document class and the packages you use, if any, to manage citations etc., as well, obviously, as the bibliography style you are using.

Comment: To me it looks as if your style relies on `author`s having first names. Your corporate author does not have a first name, but still the style prints a comma expecting it to follow. What bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated which bibliography style -- what you invoke with the `\bibliographystyle` directive -- you're using. Given the general gist of the discussion, though, it looks like the following problem is dogging the bibliography style you use. Search your bst file for all instances of the string `vv`. Something like the following make come up several times:

```
.... "{vv~}{ll, }{ff}{, jj}" ....
```

where the dots refer to other stuff on the lines that produce a match. (`vv`, `ll`, `ff`, and `jj` refer to the "von", "last name", "first name", and "junior" components of a name, by the way. A "corporate author", in BibTeX jargon, has only a last-name component, but no first-name, von, and junior components.)

If that's what comes up, you should change the strings to

```
.... "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}" ....
```

Note that there's no more comma in the last-name field and, instead, there's now a comma at the start of the first-name field.

As always after making changes to a bst file, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

If you report which bibliography style you use, it will be possible to verify whether or not the hunch shown above provides a workable solution.